# How do I setup CFReadStreamRead to timeout in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, http, network-programming, cfnetwork

I have legacy code using CFReadStreamRead on the iOS, but if there is no/loss of a connection CFReadStreamRead will block forever.  How do I setup CFReadStreamRead to timeout?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using a home grown timeout.  The code was something like this:

```
uint64_t start = get_current_time();

while(TRUE) {
     if(CFReadStreamHasBytesAvailable(stream) == TRUE) {
          while ((bytes_read = CFReadStreamRead(stream, buffer, read_size)) > 0) {
               // do work!
          }
          start = get_current_time();
     }
     uint64_t elapsed = get_current_time() - start;
     if(elapsed > timeout) {
          break;
     }
     sleep(10);
}
```

Comment: I found it useful. However, using your code gives me always -1 bytes (CFReadStreamRead returns -1). Do you have any idea on that ?

Comment: So CFReadStreamHasBytesAvailable is true but CFReadStreamRead returns -1 bytes, which means -1 either the stream is not open or an error occurs.  How did you setup the stream?  You can try using CFReadStreamCopyError on the stream then CFErrorCopyDescription on the error to get a description of the error.

Answer (score 3):

@Michael Wildermuth Yes, there was an error on opening the stream and got it fixed. Someone who face the same issue, the below code would help.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
CFStreamClientContext dataStreamContext = {0, (__bridge void *)(self), NULL, NULL, NULL};

CFHTTPMessageRef message = CFHTTPMessageCreateRequest(kCFAllocatorDefault, CFSTR("GET"), (__bridge CFURLRef)url, kCFHTTPVersion1_1);

NSString *header;
NSDictionary *requestHeaders = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"application/html;charset=UTF-8" forKey:@"Content-Type"];
for (header in requestHeaders) {
    CFHTTPMessageSetHeaderFieldValue(message, (__bridge CFStringRef)header, (__bridge CFStringRef)[requestHeaders objectForKey:header]);
}

CFHTTPMessageSetBody(message, (CFDataRef)(CFSTR("")));

CFReadStreamRef readStream = CFReadStreamCreateForHTTPRequest(kCFAllocatorDefault, message);
CFOptionFlags events = kCFStreamEventHasBytesAvailable | kCFStreamEventErrorOccurred | kCFStreamEventEndEncountered;


if(CFReadStreamSetClient(readStream, events, EvenCallBack, &dataStreamContext)){
    CFReadStreamScheduleWithRunLoop(readStream, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
}

CFReadStreamOpen(readStream);
```

And for the callback function,

```
void EvenCallBack(CFReadStreamRef readStream, CFStreamEventType type, void *clientCallBackInfo){


if(CFReadStreamHasBytesAvailable(readStream))
{
    uint8_t buf[1024];
    unsigned int len = 1024;

    CFIndex numBytesRead = CFReadStreamRead(readStream, buf, len);

    NSMutableData* data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    [data appendBytes:&buf length:numBytesRead];

    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"Network read (%d): %@", len, str);
}else {
    return;
}

CFHTTPMessageRef message = (CFHTTPMessageRef)CFReadStreamCopyProperty((CFReadStreamRef)readStream, kCFStreamPropertyHTTPResponseHeader);
if (!message) {
    NSLog(@"No message");
}

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

while ((bytes_read = CFReadStreamRead(stream, buffer, read_size)) > 0) {
// do work!
}

I don't think this code achieves anything special. CFReadStreamRead is internally implemented in a similar manner. Quoting Apple's documentation on this: "This function blocks until at least one byte is available; it does not block until buffer is filled."

Answer (score 0):

I set a custom timeout method:

```
var hasRecievedUpdate = false
var httpStream: CFReadStream?
var handler: ((Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void)?

func send() {
        let stream = httpStream as Stream
        stream.delegate = self

        stream.schedule(in: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.default)
        stream.open()

        hasRecievedUpdate = false

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + self.timeout) {
            if !self.hasRecievedUpdate
            {
                stream.close()
                self.handler?(nil, nil, nil)
            }
        }
}

 func stream(_ aStream: Stream, handle eventCode: Stream.Event) {

        self.hasRecievedUpdate = true
        ...
}
```